# ImportError: No module named apache when using Grinder Data Analyzer

Tags: analyzer, grinder

I used Grinder 3.11 and tried to use Grinder Data Analyzer for better graph result. My Grinder Data Analyzer is GrinderAnalyzer.V2.b19

when I tried to execute this,

```
" jython ./analyzer.py "<grinder data file(s)>" <grinder mapping file> [number of agents]"
```

I got error:

> File "./analyzer.py", line 34, in <module>
>   from org.apache.log4j import *
>   ImportError: No module named apache

I have no idea what really happen. Can somebody help me?

Comment: It's not finding the log4j .jar file on the classpath.  Can you post the complete output?

Comment: File "./analyzer.py", line 34, in <module>
from org.apache.log4j import *
ImportError: No module named apache

Comment: It looks like it can't find the lib directory or the .jar files.  Have you moved the analyzer.py script to a new location before trying to run it?